# jQuery / Data Tables: replace default filter field / text

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTables plugin to style a table (source: https://datatables.net/).

By default this shows an input field on top of a table that is used for searching / filtering the table with a default **text "Search:"** appearing in front of it. 
Checking this in Firebug shows the parent div with the following details: 
**id="MyTableID_filter" class="dataTables_filter"**

Can someone tell me a way to **change this text** or to replace the div content or is there a buil-in option that allows this ?

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: you want to change only the text ? search to something like for example filter: ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, thats exactly what I am trying to do. Ideally I would like to replace both the field and the text. The have something built-in that allows you to do this with other features but I couldnt find anything to change the filter piece.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try putting something like this in your script. That's allows you to modify the behaviour of your datatable. You can read [here](http://datatables.net/usage/i18n) for your references

```
$("#datatable").dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": "No incompleted albums found!", //when empty
                    "sSearch": "<span>Filter records:</span> _INPUT_", //search
                    "sLengthMenu": "<span>Show entries:</span> _MENU_", //label
                    "oPaginate": { "sFirst": "First", "sLast": "Last", "sNext": ">", "sPrevious": "<" } //pagination
            }
        });
```